# Fill parent in Corona .lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a `fill_parent` or `wrap_content` function in corona just like in android? So it will fit the background image in every Screen Orientation. Or it have a different approach to to this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any **wrap_content** because you don't have view groups in corona. You have simple groups but you can emulate **wrap_content**. There are also text modules wich will help you, check http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/

Yes you can implement **fill_parent** on every Screen Orientation:

```
local W = display.contentWidth
local H = display.contentHeight
local background

local function drawInterface()
    background = display.newRect(0, 0, W, H)
    background.x = display.contentCenterX
    background.y = display.contentCenterY
    background:setFillColor(99, 165, 204)
end

drawInterface()

local function removeInterface()
    if background then background:removeSelf() end
end

local function onOrientationChanged (event)
    print("orientation changed")
    W = display.contentWidth
    H = display.contentHeight

    removeInterface()
    drawInterface()
end

Runtime:addEventListener("orientation", onOrientationChanged )
```